# Find the maximum value for $x+y+z-xy-yz-zx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

If $x,y,z$ are real numbers for which holds $0\le x,y,z \le 1$, then find the maximum value of $x+y+z-xy-yz-zx$ and find $(x,y,z)$ for which you get the maximum value.

This is how did it and I would like to know if I made a mistake or someone has another solution for it.

Let $S=x+y+z-xy-yz-zx$

We have that 
$$
0 \ge (x-1)(y-1)(z-1)=xyz-xy-yz-zx+x+y+z-1=xyz-1+S \\
\Rightarrow S \le 1-xyz \le 1.
$$
It holds for $(1,0,k)$ and all permutations, whete k is a real number so that $0 \le k \le 1$.

Comment: You get $-1\le xyz-1+S$ if you double check your work, which unfortunately doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way/ hint:  the function is linear in each variable, so extrema will occur only when variables take values at the end points of their intervals.

Answer (score 1):

$% Predefined Typography
 \newcommand{\paren} [1]{\left({#1}\right)}
 \newcommand{\bparen}[1]{\bigg({#1}\bigg)}
 \newcommand{\brace} [1]{\left\{{#1}\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bbrace}[1]{\bigg\{{#1}\bigg\}}
 \newcommand{\floor} [1]{\left\lfloor{#1}\right\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\bfloor}[1]{\bigg\lfloor{#1}\bigg\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\mag}  [1]{\left\lVert{#1}\right\rVert}
 \newcommand{\bmag} [1]{\bigg\Vert{#1}\bigg\Vert}
 \newcommand{\abs}  [1]{\left\vert{#1}\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\babs} [1]{\bigg\vert{#1}\bigg\vert}
 %
 \newcommand{\labelt}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\text{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\label} [2]{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}
 %
 \newcommand{\setcomp}[2]{\left\{{#1}~~\middle \vert~~ {#2}\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bsetcomp}[2]{\bigg\{{#1}~~\bigg \vert~~ {#2}\bigg\}}
 %
 \newcommand{\iint}[2]{\int {#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\dint}[4]{\int_{#3}^{#4}{#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\pred}[2]{\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}{#2}}#1}
 \newcommand{\ind} [2]{\frac{{\rm d} {#1}}{{\rm d}{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\predp}[2]{\frac{\partial}{\partial {#2}}#1}
 \newcommand{\indp} [2]{\frac{{\partial} {#1}}{\partial {#2}}}
 \newcommand{\predp}[2]{\frac{\partial}{\partial {#2}}#1}
 \newcommand{\ind} [2]{\frac{{\rm d} {#1}}{{\rm d}{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\predn}[3]{\frac{\rm d}^{#3}{{\rm d}{#2}^{#3}}#1}
 \newcommand{\indn} [3]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#3} {#1}}{{\rm d}{#2}^{#3}}}
 %
 \newcommand{\ii}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\ee}{{\rm e}}
 \newcommand{\exp}[1] { {\rm e}^{\large{#1}} }
 %
 \newcommand{\red}  [1]{\color{red}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\blue} [1]{\color{blue}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\green}[1]{\color{green}{#1}}
$

$$f(x, y, z)= x + y + z - xy - yz - zx$$

Crit point:

$$\begin{cases}
\indp{f}{x} = 1 - y - z = 0 \\
\indp{f}{y} = 1 - z - x = 0 \\
\indp{f}{z} = 1 - x - y = 0 \\
\end{cases}$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$[x, y, z] = [1/2,~1/2,~1/2]$$

So the candidates for min-max are allow the 10 cases (due to symmetry) of crit points and end points:

$$\begin{cases}
x \in \{0,~ 1/2,~ 1\} \\
y \in \{0,~ 1/2,~ 1\} \\
z \in \{0,~ 1/2,~ 1\} \\
\end{cases}$$

The min cases ends up being $[1,~ 1,~ 1]$ and $[0,~ 0,~ 0]$, and the max case ends up being $[1,~ \text{anything},~ 0]$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y,z)=x+y+z-xy-yz-zx$$

Note that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1-(y+z)$

So, 3 possibilities :

1. $y+z>1$ : $x=0$ will maximize f, so $f(0,y,z)=y+z-yz=1-(1-y)(1-z)$ that is maximum for $y=1$ or $z=1$, and $f=1$
2. $y+z<1$ : x=1 will maximize f, so $f(1,y,z)=1-yz$, that is maximum for $yz=0$, so either $y$ or $z$ equal $0$ and once again $f=1$
3. $y+z=1$ : $x$ can be anything because $f=1-yz$, same case than before with $y,z$ equals to $1,0$ or $0,1$

So to conclude, $f$ is maximum for any triplet $(x,y,z)$ such that one is $0$ and another one is $1$.